Error while installing ubuntu - error occurrd while installation

Facing this one error,I tried 7 times and still stuck here .

Please help.  I was excited,  I loved ubuntu look .

Can you copy-paste the full installation log in pastebin and post the link by editing your question?

@archisman-panigrahi Actually sir i have closed log now , but all was well , only these errors occured . I will boot , copy paste log and inform you .

Did you verify the Ubuntu ISO? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu

@archisman-panigrahi  I am si sirry sir , I installed it in ntfs , ( and not in ext4 ) so my bad . I am really sorry , and thanks a lot :) .

sir but i have one more problem , like in windows chrome , I can zoom like this , a webpage . also in ubuntu , firefox , but cant zoom like that in chrome of ubuntu .

Are you looking for pinch to zoom on Chrome? https://askubuntu.com/a/1379934/124466

Thanks a lot sir !! It wirked !! loved your guidence and answer !!! Thanks a lot :)
